# Alternative to a PC keyboard

Tags: keyboards

For some reason, my fingers have started hurting and typing very desyncedly. For example, I type "teh" a lot and put spaces before I really should. The ergonomics of the keyboard is so bad. The Home/End/Insert/Delete/Etc. is too far to the right, numpad as well and mouse too. My back is bent sideways and I look like Steve Hawking. I'm wondering if there's something like a keyboard that can be used as a text input method for my PC.

It must be able to act like a PC keyboard software-wise, be powered by USB, be able to type all letters of a keyboard, be able to switch to different keyboard language layouts (for example, English, Croatian, etc.).

Is there such a device?

Comment: There are *lots* of alternatives for the traditional keyboard.

Comment: Which would be most keyboard-like and good for impatient fingers?

Comment: Do you want an ergonomic keyboard or do you want a keyboard alternatic

Comment: Alternative, unless the ergonomic one is a very good one.

Comment: You could also use speech recognition, see for example [this post](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/how-can-one-use-dragon-naturallyspeaking-to-code-more-efficiently).

Comment: The datahand sounds perfect, but they don't make it any more.

Answer (score 9):

Your operating system such as Windows or [Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15173/17907) should be able to remap the input of the keyboard to [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard), [Colmak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Colemak), or other national language layouts. You should not need any support for this from the keyboard hardware.

By the way, transitioning to a [standing desk](http://iamnotaprogrammer.com/Ikea-Standing-desk-for-22-dollars.html) may help with your back and slumping. Working with a good [Pilates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilates) trainer helped me immensely.

## Kinesis

As for ergonomic keyboards, consider various products from [Kinesis](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/). My favorite is the [Freestyle2](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle2-for-pc-us/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [kinesis-ergo.com](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/images/2008/Kinesis-Freestyle2-for-PC-91.jpg))</sub>

Kinesis offers a [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) version, the [Freestyle2 Blue](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle2-blue-pc/) (one for PC, [one for Mac](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/freestyle2-blue-mac/)). Supports switching between up to 3 computers/devices.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kinesis-ergo.com](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/products/cache_400_320_0_100_100_16777215_fs2-blue-mac-montage-636.jpg))</sub>

## Keyboard.io

The Spring of 2016 may bring an innovative keyboard being developed as a Kickstarter project. See [Keyboard.io](http://shop.keyboard.io). You can read all about this team’s development adventure.

[image]

Yes, that is wood, real solid wood. The “butterfly” shape was discovered by accident to be comfortable.

### DIY Dream

The Keyboard.io is entirely open-source, both the hardware and software. Built on top of the open [Aduino](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) platform. It can be *completely* re-programmed by you or third-parties. No restrictive license. You can even program control of each key’s individual LED light.

For the convenience of non-programmers, a simple utility app arbitrarily re-assign keys any way you desire. They even build in an extra physical key with no assigned behavior, for you to dream up an assignment.

Comment: On the Croatian keyboard, the letter ž isn't above enter, but aside it. Is there a keyboard that doesn't put it above? I hit enter accidentally so many times. So is there maybe a way to DIY my keyboard?

Comment: @Foxcat385 See last paragraph I added. You can reassign any or all of the keys on Keyboard.io.

Comment: But it misses the 3rd key after L rightwards.

Comment: @Foxcat385 Yes, the Keyboard.io rearranges the keys, hopefully in a more intelligent and ergonomic layout. If you are looking for the `Return` key, look to the left of the `Y` & `H` keys, labeled `RET` in their diagram. Makes sense as such a frequently used key should not be positioned for our weakest finger.

Comment: Interesting. I'll check it out more.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to the legendary [Datahand](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataHand) keyboard.

[image: enter link description here]

It is said to be the most wrist-friendly as you are only supposed to move slightly fingers when using it. You can configure it in the most comfortable position for you.

[image]

Unfortunately, its production has been discontinued, it is hard to find.